# Does car damage affect car performance?

Tags: need-for-speed-most-wanted-2012

Other than flat tires, does car performance degrade at all after repeated crashes?  My experience tells me no.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's either an option for this in the menus you can toggle on/off. If there is no option then no it doesn't. AFAIK the majority of racing games just use damage for aesthetics and not performance without this option.

Answer (score 3):

You're absolutely correct. Car damage, apart from popping your tires, does nothing other then make your ride less easy on the eyes.